# How to count the number of instances between two dates/times

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Noobie here, so please bear with me. I'll try to make this as concise as possible.

I have two dataframes:

`df2`: Consists of unique `visit number` for each person, time the person arrived to our store, time the person departure departed from our store

`df1`: Is a subset of `visit numbers` from `df2` (as well as some other data not in `df2`).

Every `visit number` in `df1` is in `df2`, but the reverse is not true.

What i need to do is:
For each `visit number` in `df1`, determine how many people total were present when the person from df1 arrived.

The way I thought about this problem is as follows (I provided some code below):
1. Iterate through `df1`
2. Take the `visit ID` from `df1`
3. Apply this `visit ID` to `df2` to get that person's arrival time
4. Create a `mask` using that arrival time 
5. Apply that `mask` to `df2` then just count the number of rows

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    visit_id = row['ID_number']
    df2row = df2[(df2['ID_number'] == visit_id
    arrival_time = df2row['Arrival_Date/Time']
    mask = (df2['Arrv Date/Time'] < arrival_time) & (df2['Disch 
    Date/Time'] > arrival_time)
    total_customers = len(df2.loc(mask))
```

However, when i run this code i get an error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

This is related to the `mask` i created.

I've done some searching, and it seems like this error has something to do with? Indexing? but I can't seem to make my code work. I've tried the advice in the several other threads to no avail.

Any advice, or other ways to think about this problem would be much appreciated!!!!

Thanks,

noob

Comment: `mask.sum()` or `mask.values.sum()`

Comment: can you provide a little more info like a small sample of the data in both frames?  Also, the code seems a little off as the line starting with `df2row = ` is missing closing parentheses/brackets

Comment: Looks like your `df2['ID_number']` is not unique.

Comment: The traditional way of solving this problem involves just putting all the arrival and departure times into (two) sorted lists and looking each `df1` arrival up in them separately.  Is that an option?

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback! Some answers
1. The parentheses/brackets were a copy/paste error. they are correct in my code
2. All of the id numbers are unique
3. All of the arrivals and departure date/times are in df2. What is the advantage of taking them from df2 and putting them in a sorted list?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `arrival_time` is a `Series`:

```
1    1
Name: Arrival_Date/Time, dtype: int64
```

Assuming that `df2row` is unique, you can extract the value using `.iloc`. There is also a problem in the last line... you should use `iloc[]` not `iloc()` or, as @bubble suggested, use `mask.sum()`:

```py
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    visit_id = row['ID_number']
    df2row = df2[(df2['ID_number'] == visit_id)]
    arrival_time = df2row['Arrival_Date/Time'].iloc[0]
    mask = (df2['Arrival_Date/Time'] < arrival_time) & (df2['Disch Date/Time'] > arrival_time)
    total_customers = len(df2.loc(mask))
```